# jQuery UI dialog does not open after redirecting from other page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on one MVC project in which I'm displaying data from table.
And I'm allowing user to `create`,`delete` and `edit` the data.

To show forms for these CRUD operation I'm using **jQuery UI dialog** to pop up forms. And in that pop up I'm using `partial view` to display various controls

> When I run respective page directly and click on **Edit**  link it
>   shows me pop up without any problem. For example suppose I have View
>   CurrentLocation in my Lookups controller; I set the controller and
>   action in RouteConfig.cs to Lookups and CurrentLocation and run it.

But my problem is when I redirect to the page suppose after I performs login operation it **doesn't show** pop up after I click Edit.

Here's my code

CurrentLocation View :

```
@model PITCRoster.RosterManagementEntities

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CurrentLocation";
}

<script src="~/Content/PopUp.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<h2>CurrentLocation</h2>
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_DisplayCurrentLocation", Model.tblCurrentLocations);
}

<div id="dialog">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddLocation", "Lookups", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_AddLocation", new PITCRoster.tblCurrentLocation());
}
</div>
```

_DisplayCurrentLocation Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<PITCRoster.tblCurrentLocation>

<p>
    <a href="#" id="createNewLocationHref">Create New</a>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LocationId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#"  onclick="ShowPopUp('Lookups/EditLocation/'+@item.LocationId)">Edit</a>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteLocation", new { id = @item.LocationId }, new { onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

jQuery function :

```
function ShowPopUp(ActionName) {
    var url = ActionName;
    try {
        $.get(url, function (data) {

            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                bgiframe: true,
                width: 800,
                height: 250,
                open: function () {

                    document.getElementById('dialog').innerHTML = data;
                },
                close: function () {

                    document.getElementById('dialog').innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById('dialog').innerText = "";
                    $("#dialog").empty().dialog("destroy");
                }
            });
        })
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

}
```

ActionMethod to show partial view in pop up

```
   public ActionResult EditLocation(string id)
        {
            int locationId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
           tblCurrentLocation tblCurrentLocation = unitOfWork.tblCurrentLocation.GetByID(locationId);
           return PartialView("_EditLocation", tblCurrentLocation);
        }
```

> How my code works is when user clicks on Edit link it triggers
>   ShowPopUp() jQuery method which accepts a parameter which contains url
>   to EditLocation method which accepts unique ID as parameter.

Can you please help me why it doesn't work when I redirect to this page from different page?

Thank you...

Comment: Not related, but `<a href="#" id="a" ...>` is generating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and a `Delete()` method should be a POST, not a GET - use a form or use ajax to post (you don't want this added to the browser history or have the user enter it in the address bar)

Comment: @StephenMuecke My Delete() works fine and it's a POST as well.. I'll remove `id="a"` Thanks

Comment: A post? `@Html.ActionLink()` is generating a GET

Comment: Ohh sorry.. You're right... it's a GET

Comment: You should change that. But your `'Lookups/EditLocation/'+@item.LocationId` could? be causing a problem with relative links (should have a leading `/`). Always use the html helpers so you url's are generated correctly. Try `onclick="ShowPopUp('@Url.Action("EditLocation", "Lookups", new  { id = item.LocationId })')>` - or better get with the 21st century and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks again man!! You're a life saver...
That was really stupid of me...
I have one question about Unobtrusive Javascript though..
I have added `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>' is it different than what you're saying?
please add your comment as an answer so that I can check mark it :)

Comment: Two completely different things - the script relates to client side validation, whereas unobtrusive validation relates to separating html markup from behavior. I'll show you how I would recommend doing it in the answer (give me about 30 minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="#" onclick="ShowPopUp('Lookups/EditLocation/'+@item.LocationId)">Edit</a>` is potentially generating incorrect url's relative to the page and it should be `/Lookups/EditLocation/...` (leading slash). It is recommended that you always use the `Url.Action()` helper to generate url's to ensure they are correct. In your case it would be

```
@Url.Action("EditLocation", "Lookups", new { id = item.LocationId })
```

However I recommend that you use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather that polluting your markup with behavior. Change your html to

```
<a href="#" class="edit" data-url="@Url.Action("EditLocation", "Lookups", new { id = item.LocationId })">Edit</a>
```

Then the script would be

```
$('.edit).click(function() {
  $.get($(this).data('url'), function (data) {
    ....
  });
});
```

Alternatively (generate less markup)

```
<a href="#" class="edit" data-id="@item.LocationId })">Edit</a>

var url = '@Url.Action("EditLocation", "Lookups")';
$('.edit).click(function() {
  $.get(url, { id: $(this).data('id') }, function (data) {
    ....
  });
});
```

Side note:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteLocation", new { id = @item.LocationId }, new { onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"})
```

is making a GET call which is not appropriate for an method which is modifying data in your database. The url is added to the browser history, and of course the user can just type the address in the browser to call it. At best, it will be making an unnecessary call to delete something which no longer exists and at worst may throw an exception depending on your code. Instead use a form to post the value

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "DeleteLocation", new { ID = item.LocationId }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> // style it to look like a link if thats what you want
}
```

and decorate the method with the [HttpPost] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attributes.

Then add a script to show the confirmation message

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  if (!confirm("Are you sure want to delete record") { 
    return false; // cancel the submit if the user clicked the Cancel button
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice explanation! Thanks for the side note... :)

Comment: Is it okay if I got with data-url?
So that I can use same function to edit different tables...

Comment: Sure, I just gave 2 options and both work (the second just means your generating slightly less markup)

Comment: If I'm annotating my method with **[HttpPost]** then why there's no need to write **FormMethod.Post** in **Html.BeginForm()**?

Comment: The default value is `FormMethod.Post` so no need to specify it (although you can if you want) - its really only necessary if you want to use `FormMethod.Get`